# Convert logical to string

Tags: matlab

I need to convert logical vector to string .. so i can take each 8 bits of the logical vectors and convert it to it's equevilant of char ..

```
A=0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 ;
A is of type logical
```

i need to convert it to a string , so A will equal 'va'

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`char`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/char.html) to convert a number to a character.

To convert each 8 elements of `A` into a number, there are a few methods:

```
% using definition of binary
n = sum(A(1:8).*2.^[7:-1:0])
% using 'base2dec'
n = base2dec(sprintf('%i',A(1:8)),2)
```

Then use `char(n)` to get the character out.

To apply this to every 8 elements of `A` you could use a loop or something like `arrayfun`.

```
arrayfun( @(i) char(base2dec(sprintf('%i',A(i:(i+7))),2)),
          1:8:length(A) )
```

**Note** The `A` you gave in your original question has only 15 elements so you can't really group every 8 (need 16) - you will need to write some code to deal with what to do in this case.

Helpful docs:

- [`base2dec`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/base2dec.html)
- [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html)
- [`char`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/char.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @mathematical.coffee answer, instead of SPRINTF you can simply add 48 (which is code for character '0') to A to get the string:

```
Astr = char(A + 48);
```

or

```
Astr = char(A + int8('0'));
```

You can also use BIN2DEC instead of BASE2DEC.

So you can use it in ARRAYFUN as

```
arrayfun( @(i) char(bin2dec(char(A(i:(i+7))+48))),1:7:length(A) )
```